# Is there a way to enforce a restrict a class to not have an annotation of a class that is annotated by a Qualifier Annotation using ArchUnit?

Tags: java, archunit

Want to enforce a restriction on a class to not have an annotation of a class that is annotated by a Qualifier Annotation using ArchUnit
Below are my classes

```
@javax.inject.Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER})
Public @Interface Custom
```

```
@Custom
class Test(){
}
```

In above classes, I have an annotation name *Custom* which is annotated with Qualifier.
Now, I want to restrict the usage of *Custom* annotation to any other class (because Annotation *Custom* is annotated with *Qualifier*)

Using Java reflection I am able to restrict it. Below is the code

```
Set<Class<?>> qualifierClasses = Reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Qualifier.class);
for (Class<?> qualifierclass : qualifierClasses) {
Set<Class<?>> classes = Reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith((Class<? extends Annotation>) qualifierclass);
if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(qualifiedClasses)) {
      System.out.println("Code Violation found")
}
```

but I want to implement the same using ArchUnit

Answer (score 1):

ArchUnit supports the concept of [meta-annoations](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/1.1.0/com/tngtech/archunit/lang/syntax/elements/ClassesShould.html#beMetaAnnotatedWith(java.lang.Class)), i.e. annotations declared on other annotations. As this includes direct annotations, you need to exclude those explicitly if you don't want `@interface Custom` to be considered a violation:

```java
    ArchRule rule =
        noClasses()
            .that().areNotAnnotatedWith(Qualifier.class)
            .should().beMetaAnnotatedWith(Qualifier.class);
```